# Linear operators in space of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Define by $L_A:\text{Mat}_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \text{Mat}_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ the linear operator which takes $L_A(B)=A\cdot B$, where $A\in\text{Mat}_{m,m}$. Now I have to show that $L_A$ is an isomorphism if and only if $A$ is invertible.

I have easily proved that if $A$ is invertible then $L_A$ must be an isomorphism but I'm not sure how to show the reverse implication. Any hints?

Comment: Yes that should be an m times m matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have $n=m$ in fact. If it is an isomorphism, it must reach the identity matrix for some $B$ which will be the inverse of $A$.

Answer to the edit question in a comment of mine to this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I made a mistake. $A$ should be an $m$ by $m$ matrix, so I guess I can't say anything about $n$ compared to $m$.

Comment: I'm not complaining about anything.

Comment: I am. It starts to be really boring to answer to questions that finally change etc. Write your $A$ as a product lower triangular $\times$ invertible, and you'll be done.

Comment: @RobertGreen Instead of complaining, why didn't you ask for information? Which is what I did, making the OP recognize the typo.

Comment: Because doing it very often or not, I keep seeing the same pizza-steak problem so often that sometimes I guess that we people who think twice before asking must be fools. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $L_A$ is linear is easy to verify. Also, if $A$ is invertible, then
$$
(L_A)^{-1}=L_{A^{-1}}
$$
because $L_{A^{-1}}(L_A(B))=L_{A^{-1}}(AB)=A^{-1}AB=B$.

Now, suppose $L_A$ is invertible. Write $A=KU$, where $U$ is upper triangular and $K$ is invertible (Gaussian elimination gives this decomposition). Then $L_A$ is invertible if and only if $L_U$ is invertible, because $L_K$ is invertible and
$$
L_A=L_K\circ L_U.
$$
If $U$ has rank less than $m$, its last row is zero, so also the last row of $UB$ is zero, for every $B$. Hence $L_U$ is not surjective, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you egreg! This solution makes a lot of sense. I have however not learned about decompositions yet but I had another idea.

If $L_A$ is an isomorphism, then it is surjective. This means that for any $y\in \mathbb{F}^m$ there exists a matrix $B$ such that $L_A(B)=AB=[y|0|0|...|0]$. This is equivalent to saying that the system $Ax=y$ has a unique solution for any $y\in \mathbb{F}^m$ so $A$ must invertible. Would you agree on this?